# Control flow programming in JavaScript on Codecademy

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

This program will give three choices of routes, then asks about gear, shoes and pet. After choosing it all, I use a `switch()` statement to give out the respective answers according to the user's choices.

Problem is that the response is always the one I have for the `if()` condition, meaning that if the condition is not fulfilled, it'll still log the same response.

This is an exercise on Code Academy; the site says that I've fulfilled the requirement for the program, but of course, since the result is not right, I thought I'd ask for help. Thanks to all who help in advance. :)

```
var user = prompt("Your path diverges to three roads, which one will you take?", "Forest, Mountain or Sea?").toUpperCase();
var gear = ["Oxygen tank", "Fire Starter", "Camp"]
var askGear = prompt("Choose your gear:", gear[0] + ", " + gear[1] + " or " + gear[2]).toUpperCase();
var shoes = ["Swimfin", "Studded", "BearPaw"]
var askShoes = prompt("Choose your shoes:", shoes[0] + ", " + shoes[1] + " or " + shoes[2]).toUpperCase();
var pet = ["Monkey", "Wolf", "Whale"]
var askPet = prompt("Choose your pet:", pet[0] + ", " + pet[1] + " or " + pet[2]).toUpperCase();
var choiceBank = [askGear, askShoes, askPet]
var choices = confirm("You chose to take " + askShoes + " shoes, " + askGear + " and a " + askPet + " to your adventure in the " + user + ". Are you ready to go?")
var choiceConfirm = confirm("This is your final chance, you sure?")

switch(user) {
    case "FOREST": {
        if (choiceBank[0] = 'CAMP' || 'FIRE STARTER', choiceBank[1] = 'BEARPAW', choiceBank[2] = 'WOLF' || 'MONKEY') {
            console.log("Congratulations! With those right supplies you chose, you survived to live another day!")
        } else {
            console.log("Really? You though you could survive with those supplies?")
        }
    }
        break;
    case "MOUNTAIN": {
        if (choiceBank[0] = 'CAMP' || 'FIRE STARTER', choiceBank[1] = 'STUDDED', choiceBank[2] = 'WOLF') {
            console.log("Wow! You're a survival expert!")
        } else {
            console.log("Really? You though you could survive with those supplies?")
        }   
    } 
        break;
    case "SEA": {
        if (choiceBank[0] = 'OXYGEN TANK', choiceBank[1] = 'SWIMFIN', choiceBank[2] = 'WHALE') {
            console.log("Congratulations on choosing well, you survived to live another day!")
        } else {
            console.log("Really? You though you could survive with those supplies?")
        } 
    }
        break;
    default: {
        console.log("Sorry, one of the responses was invalid, please try again.")
        }
}
```

Comment: your `if (choiceBank[0] = 'CAMP' || 'FIRE STARTER', choiceBank[1] = 'BEARPAW', choiceBank[2] = 'WOLF' || 'MONKEY') {` makes on sense. what should the comma `,` do? and what should the assignment do and what should the or `||` do?

Comment: The comma is supposed to add another condition and the or is supposed to make the condition true if any one of the elements is chosen.

Comment: but that is not javascript. and is `&&` and the precedence is before or `||`, so any or must be in parenthesis.

Comment: So how do you think I can improve and correct it?

Comment: In addition to the issue Nina pointed out, You're also assigning variables in your if statement instead of comparing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has changed:

- [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) block, now compact with `,` separated
- [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) are separated with `;`
- [`case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) block does not need superfluous `{}`
- [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) changed to some more meaningful.

Original code

```
if (choiceBank[0] = 'CAMP' || 'FIRE STARTER',
    choiceBank[1] = 'BEARPAW', 
    choiceBank[2] = 'WOLF' || 'MONKEY') {
//                ^        ^ ^
//       assignment        or and comma
```

changed to

```
if ((choiceBank[0] === 'CAMP' || choiceBank[0] === 'FIRE STARTER') &&
    choiceBank[1] === 'BEARPAW' &&
    (choiceBank[2] === 'WOLF' || choiceBank[2] === 'MONKEY')) {
```

`choiceBank[0] = 'CAMP'` is an assignment, but we need a comparison with `choiceBank[0] === 'CAMP'` and the same with `'FIRE STARTER'`. This should be an alternative to the `'CAMP'` selection. This is achieved with a [logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) `||`. The `,` is replaced by *and* `&&`. And while the precedence of *or* is smaller than *and*, parenthesis are required.

- minor change: added out for output instead of `console.log`

```js
var user = prompt("Your path diverges to three roads, which one will you take?", "Forest, Mountain or Sea?").toUpperCase(),
    gear = ["Oxygen tank", "Fire Starter", "Camp"],
    askGear = prompt("Choose your gear:", gear[0] + ", " + gear[1] + " or " + gear[2]).toUpperCase(),
    shoes = ["Swimfin", "Studded", "BearPaw"],
    askShoes = prompt("Choose your shoes:", shoes[0] + ", " + shoes[1] + " or " + shoes[2]).toUpperCase(),
    pet = ["Monkey", "Wolf", "Whale"],
    askPet = prompt("Choose your pet:", pet[0] + ", " + pet[1] + " or " + pet[2]).toUpperCase(),
    choiceBank = [askGear, askShoes, askPet],
    choices = confirm("You chose to take " + askShoes + " shoes, " + askGear + " and a " + askPet + " to your adventure in the " + user + ". Are you ready to go?"),
    choiceConfirm = confirm("This is your final chance, you sure?");

switch (user) {
    case "FOREST":
        if ((choiceBank[0] === 'CAMP' || choiceBank[0] === 'FIRE STARTER') && choiceBank[1] === 'BEARPAW' && (choiceBank[2] === 'WOLF' || choiceBank[2] === 'MONKEY')) {
            out("Congratulations! With those right supplies you chose, you survived to live another day!");
        } else {
            out("Really? You though you could survive with those supplies?");
        }
        break;
    case "MOUNTAIN":
        if ((choiceBank[0] === 'CAMP' || choiceBank[0] === 'FIRE STARTER') && choiceBank[1] === 'STUDDED' && choiceBank[2] === 'WOLF') {
            out("Wow! You're a survival expert!");
        } else {
            out("Really? You though you could survive with those supplies?");
        }
        break;
    case "SEA":
        if (choiceBank[0] === 'OXYGEN TANK' && choiceBank[1] === 'SWIMFIN' && choiceBank[2] === 'WHALE') {
            out("Congratulations on choosing well, you survived to live another day!");
        } else {
            out("Really? You though you could survive with those supplies?");
        }
        break;
    default:
        out("Sorry, one of the responses was invalid, please try again.");
}

function out(s) {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = s + '<br>';
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Suggest adding some explanation of what the original if blocks did with clarification on why they were wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much Nina! One more thing, can you please help me understand the final "function out(s, pre)" block? What is the 'pre' and '.appendChild(node)' for?

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq, pre was leftover from an other feature. the rest does basically create a tag `div` and insert the given text to it and append it to the `div` with the `id="out"`. its a better to diplay some information than to write `document.write()`.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much! :)